# I am trying to build a login page using react and firebase and I new to react js . The login page is showing nothing btw it is not showing any errorss

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to build a login page using react and firebase and I new to react js . The login page is showing nothing btw it is not showing any error.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './login.css'
import {auth} from "../firebase"

function Login() {

    const [email , setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password , setPassword] = useState('');
    const signIn = e => {

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const register = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email ,password)
            .then((auth) =>{
                console.log(auth);
            })
            .catch(error => alert(error.message))
    }


  return (
      .....
  )
}

export default Login;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Nilim, and welcome! To give a bit more information, do you mind also showing the contents of your `"../firebase"` file?

Comment: If you look at the firebase console and then go to authentication. Can you see the user you created in the list? Also don't forget to enable the email/password way to auth